# Promoted Links to Network File Share Path Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-server, promoted-links, network-drive

In SharePoint 2019 on-prem, **a promoted links list with the link location pointing to a file share network path** works well when we are in the allitems.aspx view. But, does not respond when we switch to the tiles.aspx view.

Is this the expected behavior?

I am not sure whether this was working in earlier versions of SharePoint. Could someone please guide me. Thanks.

Some related Links:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/320170/promoted-links-linked-to-file-share-not-working-in.html
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/678f2394-1399-4989-a189-f2c969a7e34f/links-to-file-share-from-promoted-links-tiles-view?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue in SP 2019. This issue can be reproduced in both SP2019 and SP Online. In SP 2016, it does not work in another way. I would suggest you pay attention to the updates released in the future.